# How to pass foreign key to json data when doing ajax call?

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, orm

I am facing some confusion about using ajax to post data to a table that contains foreign key in another table. I can do this with object binding with spring pojo but I am trying to create a program that handles client and server side data transfer purely in `JSON` format.

For example, I have a one to many relationship between `Student` and `Grade` table. The foreign key in the grade table is `student_id`.

Now if I am trying to do an insert in the `grade` table with the student id = 1. What the json data should look like?

Assuming grade table contains these three columns:

`grade_Id, grade_received, student_id_fk`

If without the foreign key, I can pass the json data like this:

```
{
    "grade_Id": 2,
    "grade_received": "A"
}
```

What do i need to change if i need the json data contains the `student_id_fk`?

Comment: Couldn't understand your problem, why you can't use "student_id_fk" key-value pair in your JSON ??

Comment: @hagrawal correct me if I am wrong. In my `Grade` entity, the `@ManyToOne` annotation is on top of the `private Student student;` variable. So I don't really have a `student_id_fk` variable in my pojo.

Comment: But while inserting you need to know and pass the student id value which is the primary key in student table .. Its not like trigger which can do something based on something, this is hard core information which you need .. Only thing is that the student id should be present in the student table while inserting into grade table .. But you need student id .. So the student object of Grade object will have the student id .. But from client side you need to pass the student id .. And this will anyways happen because presumably you are not passing NULL student in your Grade object/JSON ..

Comment: Look at my updated comment ..

Comment: @hagrawal Yes, the student_id will be available when doing the ajax call.So you are saying I pass the `student_id_fk` in the json data, and use the id to get the `Student` object from java side?

Comment: @hagrawal i thought about your suggest and tried to apply. but i don't think it works.

Comment: What did you try and what issue you faced ?? Can you post relevant or complete code of your Student and Grade class ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding a new private variable in my `Grade.java` class. I created `private Integer studentId`, and annotated it with `@Transient` this way hibernate will not persist it.

Then use the `studentId` variable to get the `Student` object.

Answer (score -2):

A JSON object such as this would provide enough information to perform an insert on the server:

```
   {
        "student_id": 1,
        "grade_received": "A"
    }
```

SQL would be something like `INSERT INTO Grades (student_id_fk, grade_received) VALUES(1, 'A')` on the server.

Comment: It is enough to do the insert, but it will not update the PK-FK relationship column. In my case, the `student_id_fk` column in the Grade table will be null

Comment: Your edited answer still does not work, there is no `student_id_fk` in the Grade.java class. The FK-PK mapping done in java side is not just use the id, it uses the object.

Comment: You've provided very little relevant information in your OP regarding how things are done on the server. Perhaps update your OP? Another posted pointed out the alternative is to fetch a Student object with the Id provided from the `AJAX` request and set the `Student` on your `Grade` object.

Comment: I added my tags to include `hibernate`